# Sphinx search:'total_found' not exact?

Tags: sphinx

I found total_found not exact through several tests:

In one of the tests, the total_found was 40379, the limit i set was (0,20), then i set the offset to be 2000 and the result was null. Not Until I set the offset much more lower it returned results.

What's the problem? Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the total variable - it is your current limit of max matches.
You can change max matches limit in searchd section of sphinx.conf

```
max_matches = 100000
```

Restart searchd.

And then in application

```
$cl->SetLimits(2000, 20, 100000);
```

Last variable is the max matches limit.

This is done in this way because of performance, lower value of max matches give you better performance.

Comment: Thank you.You helped me out of dilemma1

Comment: Mmmm ... the problem ist, that "total_found" differs, when changing "total" for example: "total: 15000" i get "total_found: 2850265" which is wrong in my case. when i use "total: 1000000" i get "total_found: 1045420", which is correct in my case. so that means, that "total_found" is always only some kind of estimation?